# R: Cannot Open File : No such file or directory

Tags: r

I have script as below:

```
setwd ("I:/prep/Coord/RData/test")

#load .csv files
a.files <- grep("^Whirr", dir(), value=TRUE) #pattern matching
b.files <- paste0("Files_", a.files) 

for(i in length(a.files)){
    a <- read.table(a.files[i], header=T, sep=",", row.names=1) #read files start with     Whirr_
    b <- read.table(b.files[i], header=T, sep=",", row.names=1) #read files start with Files_
    a
    b

    cr <- as.matrix(a) %*% as.matrix(t(a)
    cr


    diag(cr)<-0
    cr

    #write to file
    write.csv(cr, paste0("CR_", a.files[i], ".csv"))
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to compare two files which have similar filename at the end of file name, and do the calculation, and write the result to file.

When I tried to print a.files and b.files, the output seems ok for me. The output as below:

```
> a.files <- grep("^Whirr", dir(), value=TRUE) #pattern matching
> b.files <- paste0("Files_", a.files, sep="") 
Error: could not find function "paste0"
> a.files
[1] "Whirr_127.csv" "Whirr_128.csv"
> b.files
[1] "Files_ Whirr_127.csv" "Files_ Whirr_128.csv"
>
```

I tried to feed the script with multiple files, but I got an error msg as below:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'Files_ Whirr_128.csv': No such file or directory
```

So, I tried to use file.choose, but it also doesn't work for me.

Appreciate help from the expert

Comment: What *are* the names of the files you want to read? (The ones that start with `Files_` that you expect to be there?)

Comment: How can we know what is going wrong unless you print the results of the intermediate values?

Comment: @DavidRobinson , Files_Whirr_128.csv .

Comment: @user1676484: Could you please print both `a.files` and `b.files` after they are defined?

Comment: @DavidRobinson , yeap, I include it in the question.

Comment: Whoa, hold on- where did `Error: could not find function "paste0"` come from?

Comment: (Incidentally, my original answer was wrong- don't use `sep=""`. But that doesn't explain the error message. The error message does mean that that line doesn't actually change `b.files`. Perhaps you originally used `paste`? Have you been getting that error message every time you ran it?)

Comment: Aha! What version of Python are you using? I bet it is earlier than 2.15- am I correct?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, When I changed paste0 to paste, still got same error msg. And, yes, I got the error msg "cannot open file 'Files_ Whirr_128.csv': No such file or directory" every time I ran it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
b.files <- paste0("Files_", a.files)
```

to:

```
b.files <- paste("Files_", a.files, sep="")
```

You are using a version of R that does not have `paste0` (I see that code was given to you in an earlier answer). This means you were keeping an earlier version of `b.files`, perhaps one that had been constructed using `paste`.

One important lesson about this is that whenever you get an error message about a line, such as `Error: could not find function "paste0"`, that means the line *did not happen!* You have to fix that error before you paste the code, or tell us about the error when you do- otherwise we assume the `b.files <- paste0("Files_", a.files)` line works.

Comment: @DavidRobinsion, thanks. But, why it only save second file (Whirr_128), not the first file which is Whirr_127?

Comment: What do you mean it *saves* that file? It shouldn't change those files. Do you mean that it only creates CR_Whirr_128 and not CR_Whirr_127?

Comment: yeah, it only creates CR_Whirr_128 and not CR_Whirr_127.

Comment: Does the program throw any other errors while it's running that you're not telling me about?

Comment: Incidentally, did you also change `paste0("CR_", a.files[i], ".csv")` to `paste("CR_", a.files[i], ".csv", sep="")`?

Comment: Please put the line `print(paste("CR_", a.files[i], ".csv", sep=""))` immediately before the `write.csv` line. Then run it and tell me what it prints.

Comment: It prints - [1] "CR_Whirr_128.csv.csv"

Comment: Found it- change `for(i in length(a.files)){` to `for(i in 1:length(a.files)){`. Also, you'll probably want to remove the `, ".csv"` from your `paste` unless you want the extra extension.